# equalize length of the temp data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two text files(`file1.txt,file2.txt`)  that contain time_stamp in julian day in first column and temperature data in second columns. Based on the time stamp of `file1.txt` I have to extend the length of `file2.txt` by appending zero, so that the length of the `file2.txt` will be equals to length of the `file1.txt`.

Input data

```
cat file1.txt
023 4.5
024 6.8
025 9.8
030 2.3
125 1.4
129 5.8
168 1.0

cat file2.txt
024 1.2
025 2.3
125 1.6
```

output

```
023 0.0
024 1.2
025 2.3
030 0.0
125 1.6
129 0.0
168 0.0
```

In my code i am unable to insert the main portion that does the magic
I tried

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data1=np.loadtxt("data1.txt")
data2=np.loadtxt("data2.txt")
if data1==data2:
   print('same length data')
else:
   ............
```

Comment: can a time_stamp reside in `file2.txt` and not have a match in `file1.txt`? and if so, how should it be treated? (and if possible, update the question to show such a scenario)

Comment: timestamp can be taken from file1.txt

Comment: Why is this tagged as shell and awk? There is neither POSIX shell code nor awlk code in your quesiton.

Comment: @user1934428 better please provide a solution in python, pandas or numpy

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
    f2[$1]=$0
    next
    }
$1 in f2{print f2[$1]; next}
{printf("%s%s%1.1f\n", $1, OFS, 0.0)}

' file2 file1
```

Or this in Python:

```
f2_data={}
with open(fn2) as f2:
    for line in f2:
        line=line.strip()
        field1, field2=line.split()
        f2_data[field1]=line  
        
with open(fn1) as f1:
    for line in f1:
        field1, field2=line.strip().split()
        if field1 in f2_data:
            print(f2_data[field1])
        else:
            print(field1, '0.0')
```

Either prints:

```
023 0.0
024 1.2
025 2.3
030 0.0
125 1.6
129 0.0
168 0.0
```

In both cases the strategy is the same:

1. Make an index of `file2` first to see what gets printed from that file;
2. Print the julian date and `0.0` to fill in for date not in `file2`

Comment: how to define file1.txt and file2.txt in python code ??

Comment: `fn1` and `fn2` are named variables, so `fn1="/path_to/file_name"` before the `open` or use that path directly in `open("/path_to/file_name")`

Comment: how to save it to a text file again

Comment: `awk 'the_awk_program' file2 file1 >file3`

Comment: i know that...how to do it in python script

Comment: Use another `with open(fn3, "w") as f3: [write the output...]` Ask a new question if you can't figure this out. It is off topic from your first question.

Comment: please update the answer to save the output @dawg